# Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu controle do foco depois do clique

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, menu, dropdown, teclado

### Situação

- Tenho um navbar no meu site, e nele eu possuo diversos menus dropdown / megamenus.
- Preciso que quando seja clicado neste dropdown, o usuário tenha a opção de "rolar" a página para cima e para baixo com as setas direcionais do teclado.
- Com o scroll do mouse isto já funciona
- Mas o teclado não... mesmo se setar o foco (utilizando o .focus() do jquery) em algum elemento que esteja fora do navbar.

[JSFiddle está aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/7f9qA/3/), redimencionem a tela se o dropdown não aparecer.

Depois tente apertar para cima e para baixo no teclado, neste caso não irá funcionar (a tela não irá para baixo nem para cima)... só funciona com o scroll do mouse, e eu precisaria que isso funcionasse com o teclado também

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, aqui fica uma sugestão: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqdxf/

```
$('.navbar-collapse').keyup(fazerScroll);

function fazerScroll(event) {
    if (!$('.navbar-collapse').is(':visible')) return;
    var navBar = document.querySelector('.navbar-collapse');
    var scrollAtual = navBar.scrollTop;

    var incremento = event.keyCode == 40 ? 100 : event.keyCode == 38 ? -100 : 0;
    if (!incremento) return;
    $(navBar).stop().animate({
        scrollTop: scrollAtual + incremento
    }, 500);
}
```

Esse código chama a função `fazerScroll()` cada vez que uma tecla é pressada dentro da `nav-bar`. Quando a função abre verifica se o dropdown está visivel, senão pára.
Depois mede a posicao atual to scroll e incrementa 100px no caso de a tecla carregada ser cima e -100px no caso de ser baixo.
Antes de fazer a animacao para a posicao final, verifica se existe incremento para evitar correr a funcao `.animate()`. Note que usei o `.stop()` para permitir que o animate volte a correr noutra direcao caso carregue nas teclas rápido, senao ele ia acumular instrucoes e ter um comportamento extranho

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é isso que vc está precisando, mas vc pode criar um bind do evento keyup e verificar se o usuário pressionou as setas para cima ou para baixo e fazer a rolagem da tela:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 38) { // codigo da seta pra cima
    // faça a rolagem pra cima
  } else if(event.keyCode == 40) { //codigo da seta pra baixo
    // faça a rolagem pra baixo
  }
});
```

Para fazer a rolagem da tela para algum elemento você pode usar o método scrollTop do jquery:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($('seletor-do-elemento').offset().top)
},500);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas isto não seria bem o que estou precisando. O problema em si é o seguinte... Tente abrir o JSFiddle, e em seguida clique no menu dropdown, com ele aberto, tente apertar para cima e para baixo no teclado, neste caso, não irá funcionar (a tela não irá para baixo nem para cima)... só funciona com o scroll do mouse, e eu precisaria que isso funcionasse com o teclado também.

Answer (score 0):

Então pessoal, acabei encontrando uma resposta.

[Clique aqui para ver o jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f9qA/4/)

Acabei captando o evento de onclick do menu.

Evito a propagação deste evento.

E controlo a abertura e o fechamento do menu na mão.

Para isto, eu tive que retirar o atributo **data-toggle** do menu.

Obrigado pela ajuda.